# Bash shell script randomly replacing characters in variable with spaces and quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to use a Bash shell script that was written by someone who has left the firm and allegedly this script worked before.

This section of the script is not working

```
for i in $(cat $testcases)
    do
        resultsfile=${resultspath}/${i}_diff_results.txt
        if [ -f $resultsfile ]
        then
            rm $resultsfile
        fi
        echo "Started:[$DATESTAMP]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "performing type:[$type]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "test case file:[$testcases]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "input directory 1:[$path1]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "input directory 2:[$path2]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "resultsfile:[$resultsfile]" >> $resultsfile

        file1=$(ls -1 $path1/*$i*)
        file2=$(ls -1 $path2/*$i*)

        echo "testcase:[$i]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "file1:[$file1]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "file2:[$file2]" >> $resultsfile
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $resultsfile

        echo "Performing:[/global1/app/scripts/ssf_data_compare.pl -file1=$file1 -file2=$file2 -iccfile=$iccfile -resultsfile=$resultsfile]"
        /global1/app/scripts/ssf_data_compare.pl -file1=$file1 -file2=$file2 -iccfile=$iccfile -resultsfile=$resultsfile

    done
```

If I run the script with sh -x I can see it picks up $resultsfile correctly, and does the if -f, but when it goes to remove the file the variable has been distorted.

```
+ resultsfile=/global1/app/tmp/WFBNA_BDT_POS_OUT_diff_results.txt
+ [[ -f /global1/app/tmp/WFBNA_BDT_POS_OUT_diff_results.txt ]]
+ rm /global1/app/tmp/W BNA_B T_P '' _ UT_diff_results.txt
rm: cannot remove 'BNA_B': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'T_P': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '_': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'UT_diff_results.txt': No such file or directory
+ echo 'Started:[20220831123510]'
+ echo 'performing type:[comma]'
+ echo 'test case file:[/global1/devc/SIT/config/commatestpack.txt]'
+ echo 'input directory 1:[/global1/devc/SIT/data/7702downloads]'
+ echo 'input directory 2:[/global1/devc/SIT/data/840downloads]'
+ echo 'type:[comma]'
+ echo 'resultsfile:[/global1/app/tmp/WFBNA_BDT_POS_OUT_diff_results.txt]'
++ ls -1 /global1/devc/ '' 'T/data/7702downloads/*W' BNA_B T_P '' _ 'UT*'
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access T/data/7702downloads/*W: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access BNA_B: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access T_P: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access _: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access UT*: No such file or directory
+ file1='/global1/devc/:
SIT'
++ ls -1 /global1/devc/ '' 'T/data/840downloads/*W' BNA_B T_P '' _ 'UT*'
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access T/data/840downloads/*W: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access BNA_B: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access T_P: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access _: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access UT*: No such file or directory
+ file2='/global1/devc/:
SIT'
+ echo 'testcase:[WFBNA_BDT_POS_OUT]'
+ echo 'file1:[/global1/devc/:
SIT]'
+ echo 'file2:[/global1/devc/:
SIT]'
```

Characters are being replaced by quotes or spaces. I thought there might be a non printable character sneaking in, but $resultspath is specified in the command line and I typed it manually, and $i comes from an input file on which I have done cat -v and od -c to check no non printable characters. I'm stuck as to what else could be causing the issue.  Probably something really simple!

Comment: There are a couple pitfalls in this code.  Put it in https://www.shellcheck.net/ for suggestions.  Major one, using `for` with a `cat file` is dangerous and can lead to weird results.  Also make sure you do not have dos format end of lines anywhere (`dos2unix`).  You could also inspect the content of `$testcases` using `od -c` and `od -x` to see what is actually in the file.

Comment: Something has set the `IFS` variable to a weird value, which makes word-splitting of unquoted variable references do even sillier things than usual. Find the part that's setting `IFS`, and either don't do that or set it back to normal ASAP afterward. It'd also be a good idea to double-quote the variable references to prevent word splitting from acting at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem was indeed IFS. The author of the script had done IFS=OLDIFS instead of IFS=$OLDIFS and vice versa. Fixed that and the script worked.

Answer (score 0):

Per Gordon Davisson's suggestion in comments, this is now resolved.

The problem was indeed IFS. The author of the script had done IFS=OLDIFS instead of IFS=$OLDIFS and vice versa. Fixed that and the script worked.
-Dev